# How and where do I publish my open standard?

Tags: standards

I have been writing an open standard for a protocol I am developing. As far as writing concerns I have it under control. But the main question is where can I publish such document. I have been searching on the internet and didn't find such site where I could upload a TXT or PDF file. I have no intention of keeping secrets and I would like people to read this and if possible make protocol better.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Pardon for my confusion, but I find new StackOverflow a bit confusing :) I will be more careful in future.

Comment: For curiosity sake, what kind of protocol? Do you have a link to github or some shared document service?

Comment: You can publish a protocol and hope that it becomes a standard. You can even work toward making it a standard. But you really can't call it a standard until you get other people to adopt it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It used to be, and I hope still is, that anybody can publish anything as a Request for Comments (RFC) draft document at the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF). This is the perfect place to publish your new protocol:

http://www.ietf.org/contact-the-ietf.html

It exists entirely so that new protocols and proposed standards can be published, widely read, discussed, shot at, shot down, insulted, praised, and generally worked over and, perhaps, finally adopted.

You will look like and feel like Saint Sebastian for a time but that's  how all candidate protocols are handled.

Comment: Thank you. I was on that site but I didn't know they accept RFC from ordinary people like me :)

Comment: Ordinary people like you are where the ideas come from :-)

Comment: The difference between ordinary people and extraordinary people is that extraordinary people are extra ordinary.

Answer (score -2):

You could also submit your open standard draft to ycombinator.com or various reddits:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/programmer/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Programmers/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/software_design/

Your mileage may vary tho.